# How can I improve the time complexity of the following python code, if possible, else can I make it all in one line instead of this raw code

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of exercises, further each exercise has a list(array) of sub-exercises in which there is a parameter which is at index 11 depending on 1 or 0, I'm removing the sub exercise from that particular exercise list.

```
for exercise in list(self.all_exercises):
   for sub_exercise in self.all_exercises(exercise):
      if sub_exercise[11] == 1:
         self.all_exercises.get(exercise).remove(sub_exercise)
```

Can I write the code in a more compact and time efficient way ?

Example:

```
thisdict =  {
  11525: [["Ford",1],["Ford2",0]],
  56215: [["Mustang",0],["Mustang2",1]],
  96581: [["Jam",1]],
  23453: [["GT",0]]
}

#Need to modify below 4 lines to be more time efficient if possible or more compact

for i in list(thisdict):
    for j in thisdict.get(i):
        if j[1] == 1:
            thisdict.get(i).remove(j)
            
print(thisdict)
```

Result

```
{11525: [['Ford2', 0]], 56215: [['Mustang', 0]], 96581: [], 23453: [['GT', 0]]}
```

Comment: can you show one example of how the example data looks like, it would be easier to tell then

Comment: @Achy97 added the example

Comment: yes, you can check my answer @IshaanKanwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
thisdict =  {
  11525: [["Ford",1],["Ford2",0]],
  56215: [["Mustang",0],["Mustang2",1]],
  96581: [["Jam",1]],
  23453: [["GT",0]]
}

thisdict = {k: [i for i in v if i[1] != 1] for k, v in thisdict.items()}
            
print(thisdict)

# {11525: [['Ford2', 0]], 56215: [['Mustang', 0]], 96581: [], 23453: [['GT', 0]]}
```

Here I've used python's list comprehension and dict comprehension which are almost always faster than using traditional for loops.

Comment: Works like a charm, I need to work on list and dict comprehension looks like.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one if you want to do it in-place -->

```
    dc={11525: [['Ford', 1], ['Ford2', 0]], 56215: [['Mustang', 0], ['Mustang2', 1]], 96581: [['Jam', 1]], 23453: [['GT', 0]]}
    
    list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: dc[x].remove(y) if y[1]==1 else y, dc[x])), dc))
    print(dc)

    #ans - {11525: [['Ford2', 0]], 56215: [['Mustang', 0]], 96581: [], 23453: [['GT', 0]]}
```